# vNext vs ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

**Is vNext just a legacy name for ASP.NET 5?**

The reason I ask is that it still seems to crop up in newly released articles on the web.

Even the official ASP.NET 5 page url has it:  http://www.asp.net/vnext, but there is no mention of vNext anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

vNext was the former code-name of ASP.NET 5. Some months ago pretty much everything was renamed from vNext to ASP.NET 5. The 'vnext' page on asp.net is one of the few things which haven't been renamed yet - it's just an url however.

Answer (score 2):

The current name is not even Asp.Net 5 anymore. There were some big changes and they decided to rename the whole stack to a more understandable name.

vNext => Asp.Net 5 => Asp.Net Core 1.0

[ASP.NET Community Standup - January 19th, 2016 - ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSf83_TU5Yg)